# refer to a dependent typename

Tags: c++, templates, using

In the following code snippet:

```
#include <map>

template<class T>
struct Base {
  typedef T U;
};

template<class T>
struct Derived: public Base<std::map<int,std::map<int,T>>> {
  typedef typename Base<std::map<int,std::map<int,T>>>::U U; // ugly!

  void F(U u) {};
};

int main(){}
```

the marked line is ugly and also contains duplicated information (if the type of the Base class parameters changes, this line must be changed too). However it is necessary to have such a repeated declaration, otherwise the code does not compile. Also, I would like to avoid to make a global typedef declaration...

Is there a solution to refer to a type defined in a template dependant base class?

Answer (score 4):

You may pass a container type as template argument:

```
template<class T, class C = std::map<int,std::map<int,T>>>
struct Derived: public Base<C> {
  typedef typename Base<C>::U U;
//...
};
```

P.S. same thing may be done in base class.

Comment: The problem is that in this way it seems that one can choose the value of C at will, instead in my case if the user changes C the code might break in some undesiderable way. C is an implementation detail.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini so maybe `typedef std::map<int,std::map<int,T>> Map;` before declaration of `struct Derived` and then simply `Base<Map>` instead in both cases?

Comment: @W.F. this would be a global typedef with an implementation detail which also I would like to avoid.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini anyway, you should do this declaration at least one time. If you need to re-use container type more than once - you need to declare it as a class template argument. But you right... it's a dark side of C++ - template magic. In some cases it may be solved with type traits.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use at least C++11, you can combine a function declaration (no definition required here) and an using declaration as it follows:

```
#include <map>
#include<utility>

template<class T>
struct Base {
  using U = T;
};

template<typename T>
typename Base<T>::U f(Base<T>);

template<typename T>
using BType = decltype(f(std::declval<T>()));

template<class T>
struct Derived: public Base<std::map<int,std::map<int,T>>> {
  using U = BType<Derived>;
  void F(U u) {};
};

int main(){}
```

Also note that `typedef`s have been replaced by the using declarations as well.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that unqualified name lookup doesn't look into dependent base classes. So just qualify the name and tell the compiler that `U` will be a member of `Derived`:

```
void F(typename Derived::U u) {}
```

If you hate writing the whole thing out again and again, then use a new member alias:

```
using DU = typename Derived::U; // or typedef equivalent
```